# symfony2 error when creating one to one mapping

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use FOSUserBundle:

My user entity extends FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:

In my bundle I created user yml file as:

```
MyApp\EntityBundle\Entity\User:
type:  entity
repositoryClass: MyApp\EntityBundle\Repository\UserRepository
table: fos_user
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
oneToOne:
    college:
      targetEntity: College
      mappedBy: user
```

This throws the following exception:

> ContextErrorException: Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : 
>       failed to load external entity "E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\model/User.orm.xml"
>   in
>       E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver.php
>   line 732

and

> MappingException: Invalid mapping file
>   'FOS.UserBundle.Model.User.orm.xml' for class
>   'FOS\UserBundle\Model\User'.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: your app try to load your mapping out of xml. you should point it to use yml

Comment: php app/console doctrine:mapping:import "YourBundle" yml

Comment: It creates another entity called FosUser in config/doctrine.  already have User entity. I am not sure what to do next.